# Как работает UnityAction: event System.Action

Tags: c#, unity3d, события, action

В Unity Docs нашёл: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html

Вроде бы понял, что он может хранить переменные, и тип `void`.
Но не до конца понял, как он работает, и может ли он делать, что-то ещё.
Вот эти:

- event System.Action
- Delegates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> хранить переменные, и тип void

`UnityAction` - это, по сути, делегат (`UnityAction()`, в общем-то, `void delegate`). Если по простому, то колбек. Если вам нужно подписаться на какое-то событие, то вот `UnityAction` и следует использовать.

В сущности, в примере по ссылке же всё объясняется:

```
// добавление подписчика
m_MyFirstAction += MyFunction;
// подписка на событие нажатия кнопки
// когда кнопка будет нажата, то все подписчики из m_MyFirstAction получат уведомление
m_AddButton.onClick.AddListener(m_MyFirstAction);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте :)

И спасибо за ответ!
Почему-то я подумал, что он делает что-то ещё.. Видимо из-за того, что видел его впервые. :D

Comment: @Adamer так обычно и бывает со всем новым (:

Comment: Жизненно, я согласен (: